# jquery UI-Slider does not work in my code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, model-view-controller, slider

first of all, I am quite new in this area so my statement may seem silly somehow,

Im gonna use UI-slider for a price ranging,
which code or method I can use does not matter actually,

I used code presented here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_slider.htm
the third section

Or even this https://jqueryui.com/slider/
but sadly it cant work in my code, I mean when I copy the code in a text and then save it as html it works like a charm but when I copy the code in my project it just does not work.

this is my code:

```html
    @model Shopping.ViewModels.SearchModel
@{
    
    ViewBag.title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SearchResult", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<!-- Body BEGIN -->
    <body class="ecommerce">
        <div class="main">

            <div class="container">

                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">MainPage</a></li>
                    <li class="active">search result</li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            @if (TempData["messages"] != null)
                            {
                                <div style="font-family:'Times New Roman';color:green;font-size:12pt">
                                    <span>@TempData["messages"].ToString()</span>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="row list-view-sorting clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 list-view">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR & CONTENT -->
                <div class="row margin-bottom-40">
                    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
                    <!--end sidebar-->
                    <div class="sidebar col-md-3 col-sm-5">

                        @*<div class="sidebar-products clearfix">*@
                        <div class="sidebar-filter margin-bottom-25">

                            <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                                <label class="control-label">Gender:</label>

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new SelectList(Model.Genders), new { style = "width: 100%;" })

                            </div>
                            <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                                <label class="control-label">sport:</label>

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sport, new SelectList(Model.Sports), new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                            </div>


                            <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                                <label class="control-label">category:</label>

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Devision, new SelectList(Model.Devisions), new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                                <label class="control-label">Items:</label>

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductGroup, new SelectList(Model.ProductGroups), new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                                <label class="control-label">Brand:</label>

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Brand, new SelectList(Model.Brands), new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                                <label class="control-label">Size:</label>

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.Sizes), new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                            </div>

                            <p>
                                <label for="price">Price range:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="price"
                                       style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
                            </p>
                            <div id="slider-3"></div>
                            @*<p>
                                <label for="amount">Price Rane:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
                            </p>
                            <div id="slider-range" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
                                <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 10%; width: 40%;"></div>
                                <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 10%;"></a>
                                <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 50%;"></a>
                            </div>*@

                            <div class="sidebar-filter margin-bottom-25">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
                            </div>


                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-products clearfix">
                            <h2>Popular</h2>
                            <div class="item">
                                @if (Model != null && Model.Sales != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in Model.Sales)
                                    {
                                        <text>
                                            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 240px;">
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="product-item">
                                                        <div class="pi-img-wrapper">
                                                            <img style="height:70px" src="~/Style/default/images/Sale/@(item.Barcode).jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                                            <div>

                                                                <a href="#product-pop-up@(item.Barcode)" class="btn btn-default fancybox-fast-view">Show</a>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { Barcode = @item.Barcode },"")'">
                                                                    Buy&raquo;
                                                                </button>
                                                                @*<a href="#" class="btn btn-default fancybox-fast-view">خرید</a>*@
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        @*<h3><a href="shop-item.html">@item.Brand</a></h3>*@
                                                        @*<div class="pi-price">@item.PriceAfterDiscount</div>*@

                                                        @*<div style=" text-align:left">
                                                                <button type="button" style="width:34px ;height:20px" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { Barcode = @item.Barcode },"")'">
                                                                    خرید &raquo;
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>*@
                                                        @if (item.IsSale == true)
                                                        {<div class="sticker sticker-sale"></div>}
                                                     @if(item.IsNew == true)
                                                     {
                                                         <div class="sticker sticker-new"></div>
                                                     }
                                                     
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- BEGIN fast view of a product -->
                                            <div id="product-pop-up@(item.Barcode)" style="display: none; width: 700px;">
                                                <div class="product-page product-pop-up">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                                                            <div class="product-main-image">
                                                                <img src="~/Style/default/images/Sale/@(item.Barcode).jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                                                            <h2>@item.Brand</h2>
                                                            <div class="price-availability-block clearfix">
                                                                <div class="price">
                                                                    @item.SalePrice<span>R</span>
                                                                    <span>@item.PriceAfterDiscount</span>R
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="description">
                                                               <p>
                                                                    @item.ProductName &nbsp;&nbsp; @item.Code
                                                                   </p>
</div>

                                                            <div class="product-page-cart">
                                                                @*<div class="product-quantity">
                                                                        <input id="product-quantity" type="text" value="1" readonly name="product-quantity" class="form-control input-sm">
                                                                    </div>*@
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { Barcode = @item.Barcode },"")'">
                                                                    خرید &raquo;
                                                                </button>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        @if (item.IsSale == true)
                                                        {<div class="sticker sticker-sale"></div>}
                                                        @if (item.IsNew == true)
                                                        {
                                                            <div class="sticker sticker-new"></div>
                                                        }


                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- END fast view of a product -->
                                        </text>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>



                        </div>
                        <!-- END SALE PRODUCT -->
                        
                    </div>
                    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
                    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7">
                       
                        <!-- BEGIN PRODUCT LIST -->
                        <div class="row product-list">
                            @if (Model != null && Model.Result != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Model.Result)
                                {
                                    <text>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="product-item">
                                                <div class="pi-img-wrapper">
                                                    @*@using Shopping.Helpers;

                                                        @Html.ImageActionLink("LinkText", "Index", "ShopItem", item, null, "~/images/@(item.PicID).jpg")
                                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ShopItem", new { PicID = @item.PicID, Barcode=@item.Barcode  })"></a>*@
                                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ShopItem", new { Barcode=@item.Barcode})">
                                                        @*String.Format(<img src="~/images/'{0}{1}'" alt="">, @item.PicID, .jpg)*@

                                                        <img style="width:205px; height:210px" src="~/images/@(item.PicID).jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                @*<h3><a dir="ltr">@item.Brand</a></h3>*@
                                                <div class="price-availability-block clearfix" style="text-align:center">
                                                    <div class="price" style="text-align:center">
                                                        <strong style="text-align:center">@item.PriceAfterDiscount<span>R</span></strong>
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <em style="text-align:center"> <span>@item.SalePrice R</span></em>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="description" style="text-align:center">
                                                    <p>
                                                        @item.ProductName &nbsp; @item.Code
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { Barcode = @item.Barcode },"")'">
                                                    خرید &raquo;
                                                </button>
                                                @*  <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { Barcode=@item.Barcode})">افزودن به سبد کالا</a>*@
                                                @if (item.IsSale == true)
                                                {<div class="sticker sticker-sale"></div>}
                                                @if (item.IsNew == true)
                                                {
                                                    <div class="sticker sticker-new"></div>
                                                }

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- BEGIN fast view of a product -->
                                        <div id="product-pop-up@(item.PicID)" style="display: none; width: 700px;">
                                            <div class="product-page product-pop-up">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                                                        <div class="product-main-image">
                                                            <img src="~/images/big/@item.PicID+.+jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                                                        <h2>@item.Brand</h2>
                                                        <div class="price-availability-block clearfix">
                                                            <div class="price">
                                                                <strong><span>R</span>@item.PriceAfterDiscount</strong>
                                                                <em>R<span>@item.SalePrice</span></em>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="description">
                                                            <p>
                                                                @item.ProductName
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="product-page-options">
                                                            <div class="pull-left">
                                                                <label class="control-label">اندازه:</label>
                                                                <div class="form-control input-sm">
                                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.Sizes), new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="product-page-cart">
                                                            <div class="product-quantity">
                                                                <input id="product-quantity" type="text" value="1" readonly name="product-quantity" class="form-control input-sm">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">افزودن به سبد کالا</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    @if (item.IsSale == true)
                                                    {<div class="sticker sticker-sale"></div>}
                                                    @if (item.IsNew == true)
                                                    {
                                                        <div class="sticker sticker-new"></div>
                                                    }


                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- END fast view of a product -->
                                    </text>
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
                        <!-- END PRODUCT LIST -->
                        <!-- BEGIN PAGINATOR -->
                        @*<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 items-info"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                                        <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                        <li><span>2</span></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                        <!-- END PAGINATOR -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- END CONTENT -->
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR & CONTENT -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider-3").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [35, 200],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#price").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#price").val("$" + $("#slider-3").slider("values", 0) +
           " - $" + $("#slider-3").slider("values", 1));
    });
        </script>

    </body>
<!-- END BODY -->
}
```

Also this is Head section of my _Layout page which refrences to the JS needed for the UI-slider can be found,

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>adidas</title>
    
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"> </script> 
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="-CUSTOMER VALUE-">
    <meta property="og:title" content="-CUSTOMER VALUE-">
    <meta property="og:description" content="-CUSTOMER VALUE-">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="-CUSTOMER VALUE-"><!-- link to image for socio -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="-CUSTOMER VALUE-">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Fonts START -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|PT+Sans+Narrow|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!--- fonts for slider on the index page -->
    <script id="twitter-wjs" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/frontend/layout/scripts/back-to-top.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/frontend/layout/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/frontend/layout/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Fonts END -->
    <!-- Global styles START -->
    <link href="~/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
    <link href="~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Global styles END -->
    <!-- Page level plugin styles START -->
    <link href="~/assets/global/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/assets/global/plugins/carousel-owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/assets/global/plugins/slider-layer-slider/css/layerslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Page level plugin styles END -->
    <!-- Theme styles START -->
    <link href="~/assets/global/css/components-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/assets/frontend/layout/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/assets/frontend/pages/css/style-shop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/assets/frontend/pages/css/style-layer-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/assets/frontend/layout/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/assets/frontend/layout/css/themes/red.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style-color">
    <link href="~/assets/frontend/layout/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 
    <!-- Theme styles END -->
</head>
```

Hope one can save my life I am really stuck in it :(

Comment: Didn't see you loading jquery.js file. Have you?

Comment: @bipen I loaded that on the _Shared page, that makes sense pal?

Comment: No one can help me :(

Comment: Make sure you have html element with id as `slider-3`. since I coudlnt find one in the code.

Comment: @bipen I have that element too, I am gonna to update the post and add the JS, maybe something i wrong with that , I am beginner and not knowing that.    <div id="slider-3"></div>

Comment: I think you have a conflict in jquery since you are using two version of jQuery. It is very hard to debug here. But try this. See in your browser's developer window and see if there is any error. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

Comment: restarting visual studio, it then worked , its for the others may help them